# Is there a way to access a containing div from an <a> link in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I would like to do is click on an image link inside a div and have the div that contains the div that contains my image link disappear (display:none;). Right now my html has the following structure

```
<div id="one">
    <div>
        Words Words Words
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="hideDiv('#one')";>
            <img src="foo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <div>
        Words Words Words
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="hideDiv('#two')";>
            <img src="foo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hideDiv() function looks like this:

```
function hideDiv(divId) {
    $(divId).hide();
}
```

This works well enough but can be a bit cumbersome. What I would prefer would be to not need to explicitly define, by id, which div I want to hide and for the Javascript to catch the link click event and do something like `$(this_link.parent_div.parent.div).hide();`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure there must be a way!

Comment: For future reference, if you're using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ There are a lot of cool methods to move through the elements, filter them and so on.

Comment: Wow I had no idea this page was there, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having an id to containing `div`, have a common class and then use this.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        Words Words Words
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="foo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
$('a').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.container').hide();
});
```

If you don't want to add any class then you can simply try this.

```
$('a').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/MvkEa/

References:

- `.closest()` - http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- `.parent()` - http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @keybored - Did you try this?

Comment: I just did, it seems that the $('a').click is never getting the click event, is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: Did you removed the inline `onclick` attribute from the markup?

Comment: No I figured out the issue, it's because the links that I needed to listen for are being created after the page is complete. That is, they are being ajax inserted into a div. I only had to include the script in the html that gets loaded into that div to get it to work properly. Not sure if that is the best solution but it's working now!

Comment: If the links are added dynamically then you can use jQuery `on` which is added in ver 1.7 or `delegate` if you are using older version.

Comment: Oh wow, that's really cool. Thank you very much for all the info, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get an element's parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideDiv(a) {
    $(a).parent().parent().hide();
}
</script>

<div id="two">
    <div>
        Words Words Words
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="hideDiv(this)";>
            <img src="foo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, unobtrusively:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hideable a").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".hidable").hide()
  });
});
</script>

<div class="hideable">
    <div>
        Words Words Words
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="foo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your unobtrusively answer is incorrect.  your selector div should have a class of `hideable` not an id.

Answer (score 1):

An good way to do this is to add a new class to all of the divs that you want to select:

```
<div id="one" class="linkDiv">
```

Then do:

```
$(this).parents('.linkDiv').hide();
```

This solution doesn't trap you into relying on there always being two levels of divs between your link and the container you wish to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `.parent()`

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

I have the jquery documentation page up every day, it's an incredible resource for these types of questions.

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page